# Python на хостинге сайта Beget

Tags: python, хостинг, vps, hosting, vds

Можно ли, если у меня арендован **хостинг сайта** на Beget, дополнительно туда же, **не покупая VPS/VDS**, поставить Python файл?

Comment: У вас в каком виде хостинг?

Comment: Python скрипт можно запустить только интерпретатором, который в свою очередь устанавливается в операционную систему, а сайт разворачивается на сервере который не имеет собственного VPS/VDS, судя по вашим запросам, ситуация такая.

Comment: Там же написано https://beget.com/ru VPS от 210 рублей, бесплатно вы не сможете запускать python скрипт.